# Retrieving array values using indexOf

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, indexing

I've created an array like the one below,

```
var array = ['hello', 'hi', 'good morning', 'sweet', 'cool', 'nice', 'hey!', 'how you doin?', 'Thanks!'];

var index = array.indexOf('good morning')//This will return 2 since 'good morning' is located in 2 in index.
```

My question is, how can I loop all 5 values in array starting from 'good morning' and ends in 'hey!'?

I know this can be done easily by using for loop statement like so:

```
for (x = 2; x<= 6; x++){
}
```

But I am looking for a different way to accomplish this just by specifying the index value which is 2.

Comment: What do want to do? Do you want to extract those five items? `array.slice(2,7)`?

Comment: You can use array.slice() to take out a portion of the array. If that's what you're looking for. Also, I'm sorry but I misread your question and voted to close as duplicate.

Comment: What's your ultimate goal when you iterate here? There's a ton of handy array methods in modern JS that might already have the entire problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure I get it, but to start iterating at `good morning` and end at `hey!`, just use the index of the strings as start and end in the loop ?

```
var arr = ['hello', 'hi', 'good morning', 'sweet', 'cool', 'nice', 'hey!', 'how you doin?', 'Thanks!'];

var start = arr.indexOf('good morning'),
    ends  = arr.indexOf('hey!');

for (var i=start; i<ends; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jVehT/)

You could do something similar with `slice()` ?

```
arr.slice(arr.indexOf('good morning'), arr.indexOf('hey!')).forEach(function(s) {
    console.log(s)
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jVehT/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var x = array.indexOf("good morning"); x < array.indexOf("hey!"); ++x)
```

But honestly, I don't see the use of it...

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = ['hello', 'hi', 'good morning', 'sweet', 'cool', 'nice', 'hey!', 'how you doin?', 'Thanks!'];

startIndex = array.indexOf('good morning');
endIndex = array.indexOf('hey!');

for (x = startIndex; x < endIndex; x++){
    console.log(array[x])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better way to do it with built-in methods depending on your specific problem, but here's an example of how to extend the Array prototype if you really want a more handler-style iterator with args tailored to this exact need.

```
Array.prototype.disToDat = function(dis){
    if(dis===undefined || typeof dis === 'function'){
        throw new Error('No dis. You need dat and deserve to be dissed'); 
    }

    dis = this.indexOf(dis);

    if(typeof arguments[1] === 'function'){
        var dat = this.length - 1; //optional dat - runs to the end without
        var handler = arguments[1];
    }
    else if(typeof arguments[2] === 'function'){
        var dat = this.indexOf(arguments[1]);
        if(dis > dat){ throw new Error('Dat is before dis? What is dis!?'); }

        var handler = arguments[2];
    }
    else{
        throw new Error(
            "You can't handle dis or dis and dat without a handler."
        );
    }


    if(dis === -1 || dat === -1){ return null; }

    for(var i=dis; i<=dat; i++){
        handler(this[i]);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
['a','b','c','d','e'].disToDat('b', 'd', function(disOne){ console.log(disOne); });
//dis and dat

['a','b','c','d','e'].disToDat('b', function(disOne){ console.log(disOne); });
//without optional dat, it just goes to the end
```

Throws errors for:

-missing handler

-no 'dis' argument in the first position

-'dat' before 'dis'